# How to parse Json object in Jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I have a little experience in JSON I did it on my Android application now using JSON again in my webpage as AJAX reponse, I did research about ajax and found a tutorial to get my data in database using JSON so I tried but I didn't know how to parse the object.

My Jquery Code.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    url: 'functions/json.php',
    success: function(response){
   var json = $.parseJSON(response);
   alert(json.firstname) //where my response is $response['firstname']
},
error: function(data){
   var json = $.parseJSON(data);
   alert(json.error);
}
});
```

Using the php I echo the jsonArray as json_encode and heres the json output

```
{"id":"2","firstname":"john","lastname":"Doe"}
```

using google chrome console i got this error

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
```

when the function response output as alert(reponse)
output was

```
[object Object]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't parse it. You've told jQuery to:

```
dataType: "json"
```

So `response` is the **parsed** object, not JSON. Just use it directly:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    url: 'functions/json.php',
    success: function(response){
        alert(response.firstname);
    },
    error: function(data) {
        // `data` will not be JSON
    }
});
```

Also note that the first parameter to the `error` callback will not be JSON or the result of parsing JSON in the error callback.

See [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for details.

Comment: thanks you so much new in ajax best answer but i'll wait till 12mins :)

Comment: {"success":true,"message":[{"id":"2","firstname":"john","lastname":"doe"},[{"id":"3","firstname":"jane","lastname":"doe"}]}
using multiple array how would i echo this?

Comment: @RaizeTech: I only see one array in that. To loop through that array (which is `response.message`), use any of the techniques covered in [this question's answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript), such as `response.message.forEach(function(entry) { alert(entry.firstname); });`